# Pairwise minima of elements of a pandas Series

Tags: pandas, numpy

Input:

```
numbers = pandas.Series([3,5,8,1], index=["A","B","C","D"])

A   3
B   5
C   8
D   1
```

Expected output (pandas DataFrame):

```
    A   B   C   D
A   3   3   3   1
B   3   5   5   1
C   3   5   8   1
D   1   1   1   1
```

Current (working) solution:

```
pairwise_mins = pandas.DataFrame(index=numbers.index)

def calculate_mins(series, index):
    to_return = numpy.minimum(series, series[index])
    return to_return

for col in numbers.index:
    pairwise_mins[col] = calculate_mins(numbers, col)
```

I suspect there must be a better, shorter, vectorized solution. Who could help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`outer` ufunc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer) here that `numpy` provides, combined with [`numpy.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html)

---

```
n = numbers.to_numpy()

np.minimum.outer(n, n)
```

```
array([[3, 3, 3, 1],
       [3, 5, 5, 1],
       [3, 5, 8, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Great! For completeness of the output: `pd.DataFrame(np.minimum.outer(n, n), index=numbers.index, columns=numbers.index)`

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by `broadcasting`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(numbers.values[:,None] < numbers.values, 
                      numbers[:,None], 
                      numbers),
             index=numbers.index,
             columns=numbers.index)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
A  3  3  3  1
B  3  5  5  1
C  3  5  8  1
D  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.broadcast_to` and `np.clip`

```
a = numbers.values
pd.DataFrame(np.broadcast_to(a, (a.size,a.size)).T.clip(max=a), 
                      columns=numbers.index, 
                      index=numbers.index)

Out[409]:
   A  B  C  D
A  3  3  3  1
B  3  5  5  1
C  3  5  8  1
D  1  1  1  1
```